# Bash: Nested if-statement doesn't finish scope

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I have this function in bash, where an if-statement won't be run until the end of the scope, but only runs the first command after the if-statement, and then continues with the first-next command after the end of the scope. I can't seem to figure out why this happens, or why it is even possible in the first place. 

The code in question:

```
function log() {
        if [[ "x$disablelog" != "xtrue" && "x$logfile" != "x" ]]; then
                if [[ ! -w "$logfile" ]]; then
                        touch "$logfile" &>/dev/null
                        if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
                                debugout "Cannot write log file $logfile, disabling log."
                                disablelog="true"
                                echo "This, and the lines above/below are never executed. However, debugout is."
                                return 1
                        fi
                fi
                echo "[$(date +%s)] $@" >> "$logfile"
        fi
}
```

I have encountered this problem a few times in the past and have never been able to find any information about it, I'd like to find out what I'm doing wrong now once and for all.

Update: Adding debugout as per request:

```
function debugout() {
        if [[ "x$debug" != "xtrue" ]]; then
                return
        fi
        if [[ "x$color" == "xtrue" ]]; then 
                echo -e "\e[1;36mDEBUG:\e[0m $@"
        else
                echo -e "DEBUG: $@"
        fi
        log "DEBUG: $@"
}
```

The same thing happens when I just use normal echo, or any other command though. (Edit: apparently not...)

Comment: Definition of `debugout` might be required here, I suspect that's what causing the issue.

Comment: You don't need the `"x$foo" != "x$bar"` trick in `bash`; `[[ $disablelog != true ]]` is sufficient.

Comment: @chepner hmm, I have had problems with that in the past, maybe I was just doing it wrong. Will have to experiment with this a bit, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can also run the script with `set -xv` to see the actual values of the variables.

Comment: Uhm, ok, found it. log was calling debugout, which in turn called log. stupid stupid stupid. @cmh, feel free to make an answer out of it, so I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: @SharkWipf, don't beat yourself up about it, I do stupid stuff like this all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that nothing is running after `debugout` indicates that the issues lies there.

`debugout` and `log` recursively call each other, which is preventing execution after the callsite of `debugout`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder if this is also what I've run into in the past. Can't believe I made such a silly mistake so often...